# C# MVC4 Default Controller Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, controller, default

I have two controllers: Default and Page. When the user hits the root `http://localhost:1212` I want to redirect the user to Page Controller.

I used this code but no luck:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "",
            new { controller = "Page", action = "Get"}
        );
```

Any ideas...?

Comment: Exception thrown with "/"...
`The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the original default in RouteConfig to look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Make sure that's the last entry if you're mapping other routes

Comment: This works perfectly, Thanks Jedediah. But it came up with another problem, now all links in the page are going to "/Id" instead of "/Page/Id".